# OpenMPI: Permission denied error while trying to use mpirun

Tags: python, ssh, mpi, google-compute-engine, permission-denied

I would like to display "hello world" via MPI on different Google cloud compute instances with the help of the following code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

print("Hello, World! I am process/rank {} of {} on {}.\n".format(rank, size, name))
```

.

The problem is, that even so I can ssh-connect across all of these instances without problem, I get a permission denied error message when I try to run my script. I use following command to envoke my script:

> mpirun --host localhost,instance_1,instance_2 python hello_world.py

.

And get the following error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
This usually is caused by:

* not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default

* lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.

* the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.

*  compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.

* an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

.

Additional information:

- I installed open-MPI on all of my nodes
- I have Google automatically set all of my ssh-keys by using gcloud to log into each instance from each instance
- instance-type: n1-standard-1
- instance-OS: Linux Debian (default)

.

**Thanks you for your help :-)**

.

New Information:
(thanks @ Zulan for pointing out that I should edit my previous post instead of creating a new answer for new information)

So, I tried to do the same with mpich instead of openmpi. However, I run into a similar error message.

Command:

> mpirun --host localhost,instance_1,instance_2 python hello_world.py

.

Error message:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

.

I can ssh-connect between my two instances without problems, and through the gcloud commands the ssh-keys should automatically be set up properly.

So, has somebody an idea what the problem could be? I also checked the path, the firewall rules, and my ability to write startup scripts in the temp-folder. Can someone please try to recreate this problem? + Should I raise this question to Google? (never done such thing before, Im quite unsure :S)

**Thanks for helping :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I finally found a solution. Wow, problem was driving me nuts.

So it turned out, that I needed to generate ssh-keys manually for the script to work. I have no idea why, because google-services already set up the keys by using 
`gcloud compute ssh` , but well, it worked :)

Steps I did:

```
instance_1 $ ssh-keygen -t rsa
instance_1 $ cd .ssh
instance_1 $ cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
instance_1 $ gcloud compute copy-files id_rsa.pub 
instance_1 $ gcloud compute ssh instance_2

instance_2 $ cd .ssh
instance_2 $ cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

.

I will open another topic and ask why I cannot use `ssh instance_2`, even so `gcloud compute ssh instance_2` is working. See: [Difference between the commands "gcloud compute ssh" and "ssh"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062088/difference-between-the-commands-gcloud-compute-ssh-and-ssh)